# mp3 and wav files play choppy / too fast after ftp transfer

Tags: linux, audio, mp3, wav, lame

So I use lame to convert my files and they play fine on the machine. I used to scp them to another server and they would still play fine.

I started doing ftp, but un0converted wav files and the converted mp3 both sound very choppy once I transfer them...

Why would that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

default transmission file of many ftp servers are "binary"
when you connect to a ftp server, server broadcast "transfer type"
if transfer type indicates "binary" check network connection
otherwise execute "bina" and change xfer mode to binary

Answer (score 2):

FTP may be taken as an ancient protocol which normally works in ASCII mode to get file lists etc. According to protocol, we have to tell server change to binary mode before we get binary files. Looks like you are transferring files in ascii mode but all current ftp client apps I've known works in binary mode by default.